# How can I reset Apache to its original factory state on Mac

Tags: php, macos, apache

Does anyone know a way to reset apache server configuration to the factory/default state on Mac? I needed to install PHP and phpmyadmin, so I started looking at videos and reading tutorials about how can I do that (with brew) and the result is - I messed up the settings of apache big time... I'm not pretty sure what have I done, but when I try to connect to the server through http://localhost, it just says that Safari can't connect to the server. When I try to start it (sudo apachectl start) it says:

/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: service already loaded

.. but I can't access it.

Is there a way for me to fix it, or at least troubleshoot it, or if it is needed, to reset my apache configuration to the factory settings?

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Comment: uninstall, delete all settings files (if they're not removed by uninstalling), re-install?

Comment: Original config can be found under `apache-dir/conf/original` or just reinstall it.

Comment: Thank you both a lot! I managed to fix it and now I have a running Apache + php server. Can you, please, help me with installing my phpmyadmin? I installed it with brew, but when I try to access it through localhost/phpmyadmin, it says that the specific URL was not found.